# How to use Selected2 search bar in my ASP.NET Core MVC project?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, web-applications, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to Selected2 and ASP.NET Core, so any tips would be great. I'm currently working on a page for my application that's a form style. One of the fields is a multiple dropdown menu. I found that Selected2 could make some really cool multi pick search bars. I added the selected two drop down menu code:

```
    <label for="id_label_multiple">
        <select class="form-control" id="dropdown" multiple style="width: 75%">
            @*<option selected disabled="true"> Select Your Games</option>*@
            <option value="Game1"> Game1</option>
            <option value="Game2"> Game2</option>
            <option value="Game3"> Game3</option>
            <option value="Game4"> Game4</option>
            <option value="Game5"> Game5</option>
            <option value="Game6"> Game6</option>
        </select>
    </label>
```

with this javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dropdown').select2({
            placeholder: "Next Game",
        });
    });

</script>
```

also had to add the following three lines to the top of my page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel=  "stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

However, it didnt take the formatting of selected 2 css **UNTILL** I put:
'Layout = null;'
at the top of my page along with my ViewData["Title"]. So what im understanding from this is that I need to override the main Layout for it to to actually use the Selected2 CSS and js? does anyone know how I can maintain my main layout and have that selected2 bar still look nice and function as expected?

Answer (score 1):

> However, it didnt take the formatting of selected 2 css UNTILL I put: 'Layout = null;' at the top of my page

That is because `bootstrap.css` conflict with your `select2.css`.So yes you need customize some css style.

For **Bootstrap v4.3.1**,you just need add the css like below:

```
<label for="id_label_multiple">
    <select class="form-control" id="dropdown" multiple style="width: 75%">
        @*<option selected disabled="true"> Select Your Games</option>*@
        <option value="Game1"> Game1</option>
        <option value="Game2"> Game2</option>
        <option value="Game3"> Game3</option>
        <option value="Game4"> Game4</option>
        <option value="Game5"> Game5</option>
        <option value="Game6"> Game6</option>
    </select>
</label>
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <style>
        .select2-container {
            position: absolute;
        }  
        .select2-container--default .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
            width: initial !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $("#dropdown").select2({
            placeholder: "Next Game"
        });

    </script>
}
```